# Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (TinyTds::Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2008-r2, centos5

I have deployed rails app on centos 5.9

I use Phusion Passenger, when I run the site it gives me this error

```
Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (TinyTds::Error)
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `connect'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tiny_tds-0.5.1/lib/tiny_tds/client.rb:68:in `initialize'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:415:in `new'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:415:in `connect'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:39:in `new'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter-3.2.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlserver_adapter.rb:39:in `sqlserver_connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `block in checkout'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `block in connection'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p429/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
  config.ru:3:in `require'
  config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
  /home/servicegpc/domains/service.gpc.ge/public_html/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
  config.ru:1:in `new'
  config.ru:1:in `<main>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `eval'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:82:in `preload_app'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:127:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:6:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/passenger-4.0.2/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:5:in `<main>'
```